# Do we need to specifically support old browsers to be WCAG compliant or is following the robust principle enough?

Tags: legal, responsive-webdesign, accessibility, wcag

I understand WCAG is technology agnostic, so it doesn't specify which browsers, devices, and operating systems that a website needs to be accessible on.

However, our site isn't responsive on certain platforms, like Opera or IE6/Windows XP. This affects accessibility, because suddenly content will be broken and inaccessible. For example, in IE6, black text over a white background ends up hovering over a black background, [making it unreadable.](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/#contrast-minimum)

But it's impossible to account for every device, browser, and OS ever. So I feel like my only option is to be compliant for major browsers/devices, and then meet [the Robust principle.](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?versions=2.0&showtechniques=412#principle4) So even if text contrast breaks on IE6/Windows XP, I won't get sued for non-compliance.

Our goal here is to not get sued for WCAG non-compliance. We don't know how likely we'll be sued for not supporting Windows XP, but the site owner is very worried about the legalities.

[More on Understanding Conformance](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance.html)

Comment: Do you really need to support IE6 and Windows XP? Those are really really far past their end of life...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek we just don't want to be sued for not supporting them. Even though our user base most likely won't use those.

Comment: "we just don't want to be sued for not supporting them. " Interesting, you may want to expand on that. Because with that reasoning, why do you stop there? Why not support for IE4 or Windows 2000, or even MS-DOS and lynx browser for example. I mean you can not expect your site to be compatible and great for all and every OS/browser that exist since Internet was invented... So why pick IE6 specifically and Windows XP? What about old versions of Safari and MacOS for example?

Comment: That's my problem, there's all these old systems that we can't possibly all be responsive on. So which systems do we meet compliance on, in order to not get sued? I found this article on WCAG Robustness... so maybe if the responsive design still breaks, it'll still be compliant if it meets these? https://www.boia.org/blog/wcag-2.1-principles-explained-robustness

Comment: IANAL (and neither is this website) and not in your shows/knowing your constraints, but specifically trying to support systems that are past their expiration life based on the producer own data seems quite an impossible endeavor (except if you have infinite time and money). You may wish to enhance your question by telling more who are the visitors on your website and why do you fear to get sued. Browsers change, even if 100% valid today, you can become invalid tomorrow with "some" new version. Did you try various "famous" websites over IE6/XP? I bet they would not fare better than yours.

Comment: BTW I agree robustness principle is good, but I do not think it is synonym to "must support absolutely each and every old technological stack that exists out there..." Because the second part is basically just impossible.

Comment: You're right, I guess I'm not sure what is enough. I mean, if the text contrast is terrible (breaking "Perceivable" subcategory in "Distinguishable") on IE/XP, but I meet robust guidelines, I still don't know if I'm compliant or not. I will update my question!

Comment: Another thing to take into account: if you insist on supporting IE on Windows XP, it means you need to activate SSLv3, which is nowadays a big no no. It means you have to lower the security of your server, and for ALL your clients. Said otherwise: in the hope of being more inclusive you are putting everyone (all your clients) at risk. You could as well argue that you might get sued because of that. See https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=IE&version=6&platform=XP&key=18